# Getting read access violation exception, temp was nullptr, when trying to write binary search tree

Tags: c++

I'm writing a binary search tree and getting an exception when trying to access the value of the temp node I created. The exception says that exception thrown: read access violation. temp was nullptr. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. The Error occurs at the first if statement within the insert function.

```
#ifndef BINARYSEARCHTREE_H
#define BINARYSEARCHTREE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
//Default Constructor
BinarySearchTree() {
    root = NULL;
}

//Constructor with root value
BinarySearchTree(const T& rootItem) {
    root->value = rootItem;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
}

void insert(const T& item) {
    Node<T> * temp = root;
    bool loop = false;

    while (loop == false) {
        if (temp->value > item) {
            temp = temp->getLeftChild();
        }
        else if (temp->value < item) {
            temp = temp->getRightChild();
        }
        else if (temp->value == item) {
            temp = temp->getRightChild();
        }
        else {
            temp->value = item;
            loop = true;
        }
    }
}

private:
    Node<T> * root = new Node<T>;
};

#endif
```

Comment: is your code compiling for `Node<T> * root = new Node<T>;`?

Comment: It runs all the way up until the insert function.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a tree with the default constructor, `root` is `NULL`. Thus, if you try to insert something, `temp` is also null, and you get the access violation.

Comment: So in order to make it not null what do I have to do with root to give it like a null value?

Comment: Just check if it's null, and if it is then insert is simply setting root to a new Node with the appropriate value.

Comment: I still get the same error when I get past the root to insert something.

Comment: Yes... because now you got the left child of the node, which is also null. You have to do a check every loop, or just use recursion. Basically, you want to insert a node, but nowhere do you actually create a new one.